# usage of segment time in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a raw file that includes encoded data with g711 audio codec. FFMpeg decoded successfully the raw file. I want to split the wav file by time so I used `segment_time` option.
Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -acodec pcm_alaw -f sln -i g711.raw -ar 8000 -acodec pcms16le -f segment -segment_time 10 g711.wav
```

This code worked without an error but I want to know that how many wav files created. Is there any chance to know that by adding an option to the code?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 methods:

## 1. Look at the console output / log

It will output lines like:

```
[segment @ 0x55a7f065c700] Opening 'output_003.wav' for writing
```

This is the last of such lines in this example, so there are 4 WAV files (it starts at 0 unless you use `-segment_start_number`).

## 2. Just list the WAV files

Linux example:

```
$ ls -m1 *.wav | wc -l
4
```

## 3. Use `-segment_list`

```
ffmpeg -acodec pcm_alaw -f sln -i g711.raw -ar 8000 -acodec pcm_s16le -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list list.txt output_%03d.wav
```

Example contents of `list.txt`:

```
output_000.wav
output_001.wav
output_002.wav
output_003.wav
```

See the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for more info.

Comment: the `-m` in the `ls` makes accurate counting impossible